# SQL code takes duplicates in, even though I've specified it not to

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written the following code:

```html
insert into CDB2020.dbo.PartType
(
 Name,
 ComponentType_ID
)
select a.[Part Type], c.ComponentType_ID
from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.ComponentType as c on c.Name = a.[Component Type]
where [Part Type] is not null and [Part Type] not in (select [Name] from CDB2020.dbo.PartType);
```

The code takes in duplicates (e.g. [Image of duplicated values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOZTl.png)), even though my last code line should have prevented it from doing so. The last line have worked with other parts of my code. 
Why does this method not work here, and how do I prevent duplicates?

Comment: What do you mean by "takes in duplicates"? Where on your code do you believe you're stopping the creation of duplicate rows? If you *are* getting duplicate rows, is the problem actually your `JOIN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try distinct:

```
select distinct a.[Part Type], c.ComponentType_ID

from  AccessDataMigration_1.dbo.[B-K Data] as a
inner join CDB2020.dbo.ComponentType as c on c.Name = a.[Component Type]
where [Part Type] is not null and [Part Type] not in (select [Name] from CDB2020.dbo.PartType);
```

otherwise you may also try union.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no concurrent updates on the table, then you might be getting duplicates in the *inserted* data.  You can fix that with `select distinct`:

```
select distinct a.[Part Type], c.ComponentType_ID
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it’s fetching duplicate rows ? 
Better use “distinct” as a final option ,First Check your primary key and joins ...